# How to view all properties from a configuration file in runtime manager

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, cloudhub

I use configuration files for all properties of my apps, that is working fine. Running them on cloud hub I would like to have these properties show up in the app settings of the runtime manager (for reviewing or editing the settings "on the fly" without a new deployment).

I know you can overwrite them via the settings, but I would like to see the list of all properties beforehand – like if you don't use configuration files but submit them via the deployment dialog.

Any way to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Anypoint Runtime Manager you can only see the properties defined there. Properties files are not inspectable nor visible.